# Discord.py auto edit role colour

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to create a bot, using discord.py, which can change the colour of a role role every X seconds.

I wrote this code :

```
@client.command()
async def c(ctx):
    role=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='colour')
    user=ctx.message.author
    await user.add_roles(role)
    while True:
        g=random.randint(1000,16777215)
        await role.edit(name='colour', colour=discord.Colour(g))
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

It sometimes works, but most of the time I do not get any error, and it does nothing.
I'm pretty sure the `await role.edit(name='colour', colour=discord.Colour(g))` is the problem, but I cant figure why.

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is running an infinite loop that changes the colour every `0.5` seconds. Discord is `ratelimiting` you because you're spamming the API with thousands of requests. Try making it change the colour *once* (instead of in a loop) & manually calling the command every few seconds, and see if it works every time then.

Not all `ratelimits` throw errors (like for example sending a lot of `messages` at once will cause them to be delayed & only send 5 every 5 seconds, but it won't error).

Comment: I removed the loop, and tried to change the color manually using the command, but it still don't work. I dont get any error message. I'm not sure about how using ```role.edit``` and the value assigned to  ```role```.

Comment: If the name of the role is `colour`, you're testing this command in a guild, and the guild has a role called `colour`, then you should be fine. Apart from a few unnecessary things your command looks right, I just tested it & it works well for me. Have you tried printing all your variables to see what comes out of them? There's nothing _wrong_ with how you're using `role.edit`, except for `name` being obsolete, but that doesn't break anything.

Comment: So it work for you and not for me xD. Role value is color, but when i try to print something after `await role.edit(name='colour', colour=discord.Colour(g))`, it do not work. The role colour exists, idk why the colour is not changing. Again i dont get any error message, so it's very strange. Any idea ?

Comment: EDIT: I finally got this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\holyFolder\python\Discord\main.py", line 78, in c
    await user.add_roles(role)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 664, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: That means the role couldn't be found, as it is `None`, which is why I suggested printing some stuff. Make sure you're calling it in the right guild & that the name is correct.